# What does dbconfig-common do? Should I use it?

Tags: linux, debian

For several packages, the installer asks you if you'd like to use 'dbconfig-common'. After some Googling, I can't really find (in plain old English) what the heck that package brings to the table, what its purpose exactly is, and what (dis)advantages it has.

Anyone here who knows the answer?

Comment: Which packages ask that?

Comment: Roundcube(-plugins) and phpmyadmin in particular.

Comment: Interesting. What I got from Googling it was that it was a package-developer's thing, and the end user wouldn't ever need to know about it.

Comment: I got as far as "it's a package to help maintain databases for other packages", but that doesn't tell me any specifics...

Comment: If I was asked if I wanted to use it, I would just say Yes.

Comment: And that's what tutorials tell me as well, but that's not the point. I'd like to know _why_ I should use it in addition to _if_ I should use it.